# Is there a auto cache framework for playframework?

Tags: playframework

Is there a auto cache framework for playframework?

I developed my service using Django. For Django, there is a johnny cache(http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/). Johnny cache apply monkey patch to django models and automatically invalidate cache when model is created, modified, and deleted. I love it because it's so simple.

I have a plan to make my new service using playframework because playframework is awesome, but I couldn't find any appropriate cache framework. Anybody can recommend me a nice cache framework for playframework?

Answer (score 2):

If your are talking about :

- Models caching : Done through [hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/), no need to implement anything
- Data caching : Play embeed [Cache API](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/cache#api) to store what you want serialized. You can enable a MemCache implementation if you need. For play 2.0 there are also [plugins](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Modules) for Memcache or Redis.
- Template caching : You can have a look at [Rythm](http://www.playframework.org/modules/rythm) for that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but it seems you want to use Play [Cache](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/cache). Play has a very good documentation, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you question as well, but if you are looking for cache of model objects, then go through documentation of Hibernate caching -> Play model is built on top of Hibernate, which itself includes various caching methods. I do not have much experience with it myself yet, but the using of such second level cache is as simple as annotating a model class with a @Cache annotation. Google for "Hibernate @Cache".