# Caching Models in Playframework. Where I have to put caching code?

Tags: caching, playframework, memcached, playframework-1.x

Could you explain to me - how can I use memcached in playframework? 
**Where** I have to put Models in cache?

In example on official site  they put code for caching in Controllers, but I think this is bad idea - Controller methods become too complicated and I have to repeat the same parts of code.

I try to put caching code in Model's methods(Overide save() and delete()):

```
@Override
public News save() {
News news = super.save();
List<News> newsList = News.findAll();
Cache.set("news", newsList);
return news;
}
```

But I have more methods for save and delete! For example:

```
public static int deleteAll();
```

and

```
public static int delete(String query, Object... params);
```

I can't Override them because they are static (and in last one I can't recive information about deleted objects).

**What I have found about this topic on the internet:**

Among answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512154/is-there-a-auto-cache-framework-for-playframework) I find:
"Models caching : Done through hibernate, no need to implement anything"
**What does it mean?** How can I switch on this option?

And [here](https://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/d8e25dd8346aec68/0c713a2140dd1dab?lnk=raot) there are some information about hibernate caching. It is nesessary to put variables in application.conf:

```
hibernate.cache.provider_class=com.googlecode.hibernate.memcached.Memcached CacheProvider 
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true 
hibernate.memcached.servers=127.0.0.1:11211 
hibernate.memcached.cacheTimeSeconds=300
```

But I have not find any information about this variables on oficial site.

I need help! How to do caching correctly?
Thanks!